# ng-click triggering all the elements in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

when I try to click a link in one of the elements in ng-repeat,all the links in the ng-repeat are getting triggered.checked relevant questions but couldnt get much help.

PFB the plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/IZRulMaoyuS0GkWgXe7a?p=preview

```
        <div class="content-main" ng-repeat="level in list.data.left">
    <div class="content-flexbox-row">

      <div class="content-first padding20">
        <div class="approver-names margin25" ng-repeat="approver in list.data.left[$index]">
          <div class="content-left-close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <div class="approver-group">
            <div class="group group-id">{{::approver.GroupId}}</div>
            <div class="group group-name">{{::approver.Name}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="group-image">
            <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="approver-names add-approver-hover" ng-click="autoComplete(this,$event, $index);" ng-if="flag==true">+ ADD SELECTOR</div>
                                 <div ng-if="flag==false">test data </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-second padding20">
        <div class="approver-names">
          <div>{{$index+1}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-third padding20">
        <div class="approver-names margin25" ng-repeat="endorser in list.data.right[$index]">
          <div class="group-image">
            <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="approver-group">
            <div class="group group-id">{{::endorser.GroupId}}</div>
            <div class="group group-name">{{::endorser.Name}}</div>

          </div>
           <div class="content-right-close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="approver-names">+ ADD SELECTOR</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: _when I try to click a link in one of the elements_ and yet, there are no `<a>` elements in your example

Comment: is this what you are trying to achieve? 

https://plnkr.co/edit/wHGLUZmkjD1e3Mt6y2xD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are using an unique variable 'flag' for all the items in your ng-repeat.

You have to use an array of flags, for example.